# Supertype/subtype of weak/associate entity in ERD

Tags: sql, database, entity-framework, erd

I have some questions need to be answered. The requirement is to build a database for university entrance system:
 "Applicant **may** apply to 5 university, each university **may or may not** interview the applicant, then, make an offer to the applicant. The offer **may or may not** be conditional (conditional/uncondtional), if the offer is conditional, the conditions are stored. The applicant need to choose which conditional offers he/she wishes to accept, up to maximum of 3. If any of the conditions is met when end of the year, the offer becomes unconditional, then, applicant may accept that one."

There are some notable points:

- The course work requires using some enhanced ER features such as supertype/subtype.
- Regardless the offer is conditional or unconditional, the applicant can accept the offer. Am I right?
- In my ERDs, the APPLICATION entity is a weak entity, using a surrogate key, and UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT on University_ID and Applicant_ID.

In my ERD (on working), there are 2 versions. The ERD_1 is a suggestion of my friends. But I think, my work on ERD_2 is more accurate. I have questions:

- Am I correct when use a surrogate in the APPLICATION entity? OR using composite of University_ID and Applicant_ID is a primary key?
- Could APPLICATION entity be an associate entity? If it is, it could have some subtypes?
- In ERD_2, how to show the ACCEPT relationship between APPLICANT and OFFER entity? AND how to show the MAKE relationship between UNIVERSITY and OFFER?

[ERD_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mi7A4.jpg)
[ERD_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI7om.jpg)
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: schoolwork, seriously????

Comment: yes, it is. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What would you like to know?

Comment: As I said, I would like to know whether a weak entity may have some subtypes or not. And if you look at the requirement and my ERDs, how do I depict "APPLICANT accept offer" and "UNIVERSITY makes offer" in my ERD, because APPLICANT and UNIVERSITY are not relate with OFFER table, but the APPLICATION?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of no reason why a weak entity could not be analyzed into subtypes  (aka subclasses aka specializations).  However, your two ERDs suggest that your analysis of your case is not one of specializations.  In particular, in your first ERD, you use the word "has" to describe the relationship between an application and an interview or an offer.

"Has-a" relationships are typically not generalization-specialization relationships.  "Is-a" relationships typically are.  Example:  An auto is a vehicle and a truck is a vehicle.

There is an entirely different issue here when it comes to what tables, columns, and constraints you will use to implement your model.  That's a design issue rather than an analysis issue.

I don't understand your case well enough to agree or disagree with your analysis of your case.